# What is difference between BTU and MBH for house furnaces?

Tags: heating

When selecting a new house furnace most calculators display results as BTUs (based on the square footage, number of levels, estimated temperature, etc). What's interesting is that most new furnaces are spec'ed at MBH.

What is the difference or correlation?

Comment: 1 MBH = 1000 BTU/hr. Thousand BTUs per Hour (MBH).

Comment: so if I need a 16,000 BTU furnace should I be looking for a 16 MBH unit?

Comment: Maybe...  BTU is how much heat is produced at one instance, BTU/hr is the amount of heat produced in an hour. MBH is 1000 BTU/hr. However, BTU is sometimes used as an equivalent to BTU/hr, so the conversion might work. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_thermal_unit) has an article that might clear things up.

Comment: My SI prefix alarm is blaring in my head about the use of M (Mega) to mean 1,000x (K or Kilo). I'll accept only because BTUs aren't metric. But in my heart I know it should be KBH.

Comment: @shufler the M is the Roman numeral for 1000, not M for mega.

Comment: A Roman prefix for a British unit you say!

Comment: I believe M is the Roman numeral = 1000

Comment: *mille* or *mil* means thousand in at least French, Italian, Portuguese, and Spanish.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

BTU is how much heat is produced at one instant, BTU/hr is the amount of heat produced in an hour. MBH is 1000 BTU/hr. However, BTU is sometimes used as an equivalent to BTU/hr, so the conversion might work. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_thermal_unit) has an article that might clear things up.

1 MBH = 1000 BTU/hr. Thousand BTUs per Hour (MBH).

*Comment converted to answer*

Answer (score 1):

MBH is thousands of BTUs per hour. BTU is a unit of measurement for energy. One BTU is equal to the amount of energy used to raise the temperature of one pound of water one degree Fahrenheit.

The comments provided your answer, but no one posted the actual answer for you to accept.